# I want to print html file directly to printer with A5 Landscape settings in electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I want to print html file directly to printer with A4 Landscape settings. In that Html file I added this **@media print{@page {size: A5 landscape; }}** Css but its not working expected, It always return A4 portrait. Please explain anyone how I can achieve my requirement.

```
let contentWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    plugins: true
  }
})

contentWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => contentWindow.hide())

fileName = path.join(__dirname, './printtemp/print.html')
contentWindow.loadURL(fileName);

contentWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {

  var printPDf = () => {
    contentWindow.webContents.print({ silent: true, printSelectionOnly: true });
  }
  setTimeout(printPDf, 3000)


});
```

current result:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `I want to print html file directly to printer with A5 Landscape settings.`? (A5 instead of A4)

Comment: Yes, your right

Comment: Would you mind editing your question please?

Comment: In `print.html` file how you are applying css? It is inline css or add reference of css file?

Comment: I am using Internal style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I had tried many ways but nothing seems to work as expected.
I have a quick solution which I used. This solution like you are printing A4 size but half! but you can achieve your goal. I had not made PDF I just printed the window.

Add A4 size instead of A5 landscape:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
}

html,
body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 148mm;
    /* border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px; */
}
```

Make sure to add A5 paper in landscape position in the printer. I hope this will help you in meanwhile you find a correct way to do.

Comment: I also made A5 layout if you are interested then let me know. that is also a quick solution because A5 is not working correctly with an electron.js.